# Shouldn't "the exact same" always be "exactly the same"?

Tags: grammaticality

I've always avoided using the common phrase "the exact same" because it sounds incorrect to me (unless perhaps a comma were inserted thus: "the exact, same".) Shouldn't "the exact same" be "exactly the same"?

Comment: SFAICT nobody inserts a comma in "the exact same"; the phrase can stand by itself, punctuation-less. Which to use seems to be a matter of taste (viz. "He keeps wearing the exact same pair of pants" vs. "He keeps wearing exactly the same pair of pants", but the former sounds better for me.)

Comment: The _British National Corpus_ reports that _exactly the same_ is found in 1329 sentences, and _exact same_ in 22 sentences. The _Corpus of Contemporary American_ reports that in academic texts, _exactly the same_ is used more times (6 times more) than _exact time_.

Comment: A third variant exists, doesn't it: "the same exact..."

Answer (score 11):

According to these Google Ngrams, both American and British English use *exactly the same* more than *the exact same*. Here is the usage in [American English](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=the+exact+same%2C+exactly+the+same&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3):

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=the%20exact%20same%2Cexactly%20the%20same&corpus=5&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000

And here it is in [British English](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=the+exact+same%2C+exactly+the+same&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3):

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=the%20exact%20same%2Cexactly%20the%20same&corpus=6&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000

Despite its usage, *the exact same* is considered informal (but is not deemed incorrect) by this site at [Washington State University](http://public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/exact.html):

> In casual speech we often say things like, “The fruitcake he gave me was the exact same one I’d given him last Christmas,” but in formal English the phrase is “exactly the same.”

However, there is a long [discussion of the phrase](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/11/the-exact-same-time.html) which writes that:

> The traditional construction is “exactly the same time,” with an adverb (“exactly”) properly modifying an adjective (“same”).
>
> Critics of a phrase like “the exact same time” condemn it because “exact” (an adjective) is being used as an adverb (like “very”)....

Proponents of the phrase note, however:

> Elsewhere, the Cambridge Grammar notes that noun phrases including “the same” often include modifiers to reflect varying degrees of sameness. Sometime modifiers come after “the” (as in “the very same mistake”), and sometimes before, as with “much,” “almost,” “roughly,” and “exactly.”
>
> I would add “exact” to the list of modifiers that can follow “the” (as in “the exact same mistake”). In my opinion, this usage is acceptable in all but the most formal writing.
>
> If you’d like another authority, The Columbia Guide to Standard American English also says “exact same” is “standard in all but the most formal and oratorical contexts.”

Both phrases are redundant, and *the exact same* can be considered correct or not depending on which style guide one subscribes to. An American English grammar guide specifically mentions that the phrase is mostly standard, and a British English guide notes that there are similar phrases. So use depends on context: in formal writing, avoid it, but in anything else *the exact same* can be (again, it depends on who you follow) acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I can imagine a slight difference.

> Mike's car is exactly the same car as Jennifer's.

So, Mike got the same make, model, color, and accessories as Jennifer did.

> Mike's car is the exact same car as Jennifer's.

Mike's car not only looks like Jennifer's car, it *is* Jennifer's car.  Maybe Mike bought it or borrowed it or stole it from Jennifer...

Comment: This is something I was thinking as well, but I don't know whether there's any evidence to back up this usage difference!

Comment: I was thinking something similar:  "to be X", "to be exactly X" (where exactly modifies the verb to be), and "to be the exact same" (where "exact same" functions as an object)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like "same" is being treated as a noun in this case and "exact" is an adjective, where both entities are being compared to a single noun "the exact same".

> Mike's car and Jennifer's car are both the **right car**.
>
> Mike's car and Jennifer's car are the **exact same**.

Comment: Why use the modifier exact at all? Why not simply Mike’s car and Jennifer’s car are the same car.  (=The ‘exact same car’).  Vs Mike’s car and Jennifer’s car are the same.

Comment: Although you can have "the very same" despite "very" being an adverb, so I'm not entirely sure how to parse either. Maybe "same" is an adjective, although then you would have to explain how "exact" can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, yes. "The exact same" sounds (to my British ears, at least) like an American phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The expression *the exact same [X]* can often be heard in US informal speech (TV dramas are rife with it), whereas (in my experience) it is still something of a rarity in the UK.

Sloppy? Perhaps it is -- but then again, it is the norm for spoken language to be the product of imperfect improvisation.

Answer (score 0):

People use the word 'same' in sentences like 'the same car' (where same is an adjective and will take adverbs) or 'I'd like the same!' (where same is a pronoun and will take adjectives).

The problem is that sometimes people use the word same as a pronoun (by putting adjectives in front of it) when they use it in front of another noun. In front of another noun, though, it can only be an adjective and not a pronoun.

In its adjective form, it cannot take adjectives - only adverbs, like any adjective at that.

Examples (not the best ones, but I hope they make my point):
'The taxi you and I used on new year's eve was the exact same!' (pronoun)
'On new year's eve you and I used exactly the same taxi!' (adjective)

Conclusion: when used together with another noun, it's an adjective and must be garnished as such.

Comment: @AndyT I'm sorry, but I meant for my answer to only apply when 'the same' was used as an adjective; e.g. 'the exact same car', which is wrong because same here is an adjective. When 'same' is used without another noun, then it is a pronoun indeed, falsifying my statement. -- edit: Added to my answer.

Comment: @AndyT And done.

Comment: Much better. My previous comments are no longer relevant and will be deleted forthwith.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain my views on this, ending with a conclusion.

First off, 'the exact same' is a tautology - a redundancy. There is no need to add the word 'exact' when you've already said 'the same' or vice versa. For example, we say ''it's the same car I saw yesterday'', OR ''it's the exact car I saw yesterday''. In other words, 'the exact' and 'the same' have the same function. I would argue that combining these two phrases could even confuse people who aren't native speakers of English, in that they'll start wondering if there is a difference between 'the same' and 'the exact', or they could even start assuming the two words always mean the same thing regardless of context.

Secondly, English doesn't use adverbs as adjectives (except in the case of weekly, hourly, etc) probably precisely because it can get confusing. It does use adjectives as adverbs sometimes - in the case of 'drive fast', which I believe is also not accepted by most language authorities, but this usage can at least be understandable. I think a case can be made for it being an acceptable usage, but that's a discussion for another time.

The phrase ''the exact same'' is, technically speaking, wrong. The only reason why it is considered acceptable, is because it is now in common usage.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective. Please provide some references.

Comment: If it's in common usage, then by definition it is not wrong.  Common usage is the only determinant of correctness in language.

Comment: It's more emphatic than just "the same". So it's not a redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

I am no grammar expert.  However, I am fairly confident that in this case, those who use the phrase "exact same" are not speaking proper English.

There are two distinct problems with the ubiquitous (and incorrect) phrase "exact same."  This is a case of a mistake being made so often by so many people that others begin to believe that it is not a mistake.  However, sometimes in a vote of 100 who vote "yes" and a single person who votes "no," the sole person who stands against the 100 is in the right, and everyone else is in the wrong.

One distinction between the phrases, "exact same," and "exactly the same" is that the that former phrase contains two mistakes, whereas the latter phrase contains only one.  Both of these phrases have a problem with redundancy.  However, at least the phrase "exactly the same" is grammatically correct.  The phrase "exact same" is one of the more irritating phrases that is currently fashionable.  Not only does it use words redundantly, but it is also wrong grammatically.

The word "ain't" is also used very often.  However, both "ain't and "exact same" are incorrect English, irrespective of whether the speaker is in England, the USA, or any other English speaking country.  Yes, many people make these mistakes, and, yes, many people understand the gist of what the speaker means.  But, this is not enough to make the usage of "ain't, or "exact same" correct.  Neither can be considered proper English.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. There doesn't appear to be anything in this answer which makes it different from several others, nor does it explain **why** "the exact same" is wrong: you simply assert that it is. Could you [edit your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/477879/edit) to improve it?

Comment: Hi K., welcome to EL&U. Please note, this site is different from others: it's not a forum, and personal views and grammar gripes don't constitute the kind of answer we're looking for. An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. See [answer] for further guidance, and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Comment: @K. Walten Spann I'm sure you are righteously incensed, this is however a question and answer site, following Chappo's advice is best to begin with.

Comment: If both "the exact same" and "exactly the same" are redundant, does it follow that "more or less the same" is nonsensical? How about "for all intents and purposes the same"? And is "essentially the same" nonsensical or redundant?

Comment: It's not a mistake.  There is no "correctness" in language outside of common usage.  When it comes to language, the one person in the 99 vs. 1 scenario is wrong, because correctness in language is determined entirely by common usage.  This is Linguistics 101-level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am coming to the forum a few years late, but for those arguing that ”exactly the same” is redundant, not necessarily.

Consider:

Their cars were almost the same.

versus

Their cars were exactly the same.

In other words, there can be degrees of ”sameness” or similarity, if you will, so the ”exactly” (or gods help us ”exact”) modifier may be appropriate in some instances.

And an interesting bit on ”ain’t”:

https://blog.oup.com/2006/08/the_much_vilifi/